# Laravel error after [composer update=>commit=>push=>pull]

Tags: php, git, deployment, laravel-5.1

Well, I added a package, `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"` to be specific, inside my laravel app, and updated(for sending email). Then I committed the changes to the local repo (git), and pushed to the remote repo on Bitbucket. And finally I pulled the changes on my VPS server. It's worth mentioning that I have done this same process a hundred times without any problems whatsoever and I don't have any clue why it's being such a jerk this time :-|

OK, here's the problem: Blank white screen screen and when I do `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set....` I get this error message:

```
Warning: require(/home/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/.../vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54
```

Oh, and by the way, the project is totally working fine on my local machine without any problems.

Thanks a lot, appreciate it :-)

### EDIT:

I also tried running these:

- running `composer update`
- deleting `vender/` and `composer.lock` and
  then running the above command

and they didn't work because I saw the same error during the execution of `composer update` because it was calling artisan.

Comment: Try to use `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @aldrin27 Thaaaaaanks, it solved that one, but now it says: `Trait 'Illuminate\Database\DetectsLostConnections' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `aldrin27` I solved the error by dumping the autoloads using:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But then there was this error:

```
Trait 'Illuminate\Database\DetectsLostConnections' not found
```

For some odd reason that file was missing and I had to create it manually to fix the problem.